# Adding time from OCR to current time with datetime

Tags: python

This little datetime issue that is fuzzing my mind. I have a function that reads datetime out of a region in the screen. It returns time in the format HH:MM:SS.

I'm trying to add prod_time to time_now using relativedelta. How can I do that?

```
time_now = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
prod_time = datetime.strptime(str(OCR(310, 403, 434, 457)), '%H:%M:%S')
print(time_now)
print(prod_time)
end_time = time_now + timedelta(hours=prod_time.hour, minutes=prod_time.minute, seconds=prod_time.second)
print(end_time)
```

result is:

> 11/05/2020 11:41:03
>
> 1900-01-01 07:59:10
>
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str

Comment: convert the timedelta to str? `end_time = time_now + str(timedelta(hours=prod_time.hour, minutes=prod_time.minute, seconds=prod_time.second))`

Comment: Then I get `ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'`

Comment: what are the values of `prod_time`? looks like it may not be finding anything. Also, which OCR library are you using?

Comment: Wait! You were right. I moved the object and it wasn't reading time. Thanks! Consider answering, please, if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `timedelta` to `str`

```py
end_time = time_now + str(timedelta(hours=prod_time.hour, minutes=prod_time.minute, seconds=prod_time.second))
```